# VueJS - template variables not reactive with data variable

Tags: vue.js, socket.io

I'm making a chat system with socket.io and VueJS, so customers can talk to an admin. But when a client connects to the server, the variable in the data() updates. But the template is not updating.

Here is my code:

```
<template>
<div>
    <div class="chats" id="chat">
        <div class="chat" v-for="chat in chats">
            <b>{{ chat.clientName }}</b>
            <p>ID: {{ chat.clientID }}</p>
            <div class="jens-button">
                <img src="/icons/chat-bubble.svg">
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</template>

<script>


    let io = require('socket.io-client/dist/socket.io.js');

    let socket = io('http://127.0.0.1:3000');

    export default {
        name: 'Chats',
        data() {
            return {
                chats: [],
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            this.getClients();
            this.updateClients();
        },
        methods: {
            getClients() {
                socket.emit('get clients', true);
            },
            updateClients() {
                socket.on('update clients', (clients) => {

                    this.chats = clients;

                    console.log(this.chats);
                });
            }
        },

    }
</script>
```

Then I get this, the box is empty:

[image]

But I need to get this, this will only appear when I force reload the page. I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

[image]

Comment: At first, your code is correct. I saw the `console.log` in method `updateClients`, please post here this log.

Answer (score 0):

Oke, I've found out where the problem was, in another component I used plain javascript which brokes the whole reactive stuff.